# Function inheritance on Delphi error

Tags: delphi

I would like to know why I'm having an "Incompatible Types" error message on the following code. The result I'm looking for to the TInheritanceClass is 'Test String Passed'.

```
TBaseClass = class
  function Test: String; virtual;
end;

TDerivedClass = class(TBaseClass)
  function Test: String; override;
end;

function TBaseClass.Test: String;
begin
  Result := Result + ' Passed';
end;

function TDerivedClass.Test: String;
begin
  Result := 'Test String';
  inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function TInheritanceClass.Test: String;
begin
  Result := 'Test String';
  inherited;
end;
```

The statement `inherited` is appropriate when calling an inherited method for a procedure. For a function you would need to write:

```
Result := inherited;
```

or:

```
Result := inherited Test;
```

The base class method is also wrong. You wrote:

```
function TBaseClass.Test: String;
begin
  Result := Result + ' Passed';
end;
```

It is a mistake to read a function result variable before initializing it. It looks like you are trying to pass data to the base class method via the function result variable. Whilst current implementation details mean that this might appear to work, it is a fairly gross violation of design principles. Do not attempt anything like this.

Probably you need a slightly more complex structure. Perhaps like this:

```
type
  TBaseClass = class
  public
    function TestName: string; virtual; abstract;
    function TestPassedText: string;
  end;

  TDerivedClass = class(TBaseClass)
  public
    function TestName: string; override;
  end;

function TBaseClass.TestPassedText: String;
begin
  Result := TestName + ' Passed';
end;

function TDerivedClass.TestName: String;
begin
  Result := 'MyName';
end;
```

Comment: Now I can see my confusion, inherited procedures and functions have different behaviours. Thank you.